# Which databases support BATCH INSERT syntax?

Tags: sql, ansi-sql-92

I know, MySQL supports `BATCH INSERT` syntax like:

```
INSERT INTO `table_1` values(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5), (5, 6, 7);
```

Is this syntax included in SQL-92 format? If not, witch data bases support this syntax?

Comment: SQL Server **2008** and newer also supports this

Comment: FWIW Yes its part of SQL-92; 7.2  <table value constructor>

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about portability, many databases support:

```
INSERT INTO "table_1"
    select 1, 2, 3 union all
    select 3, 4, 5 union all
    select 5, 6, 7;
```

(Offhand, SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL, Teradata.)

And most of the rest support:

```
INSERT INTO "table_1"
    select 1, 2, 3 from dual union all
    select 3, 4, 5 from dual union all
    select 5, 6, 7 from dual;
```

(Offhand, Oracle, MySQL)

Access and DB2 (offhand) don't support either of these syntaxes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . That is actually funny in the context of this query and my answer.  Although escaping isn't necessary, I put in double quotes because that is standard.